# Bitcoind slow to get new address

Tags: php, bitcoin

so I have this code:

```
<?php 
require_once "jsonRPCClient.php";
$bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient("http://user:password@127.0.0.1:28332");

$addr=print_r($bitcoin->getnewaddress (),true); echo "\n";

$received=print_r($bitcoin->getreceivedbyaddress($addr), true) ;

echo "addr=".$addr; echo "\n";
echo 'recu='.$received; 

$amount=1;
$i=0;

while ( $received < $amount)
{
    $i+=1;
    $received=print_r($bitcoin->getreceivedbyaddress($addr), true);
    sleep(4);

}
print 'done !,'.$received.'BTC received';

?>
```

But the problem is that Firefox can't load it because how slow it is...
I've tried to comment some lines, and I've deducted that the bogus line is this one:

```
$addr=print_r($bitcoin->getnewaddress (),true); echo "\n";
```

When I launch the script with the php "compilator" from Geany, it works very well, but not with the web browser...
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line that you call "bogus" generates a new receiving address in your wallet. In an empty wallet, the rate for a Quad-Core processor is 3/sec while for an i3 processor it gets as high as 50/sec. This rate falls when more addresses are being added to your wallet.dat, so if it slows down the process I would guess your wallet.dat file has become pretty big. One way to fix this is to transfer you funds to another wallet, delete the wallet.dat file and the next time you start your client a new one will be created and this process will run much faster.